# Multiplayer building strategy game iPhone app on the App Store

Tags: ios, game

I am looking for an iOS game app with some substance:

- There are a lot of apps that are rigged towards you paying real money. What I want is an app that doesn't draw such a huge line between spenders and free players.
- I also want a game that takes more strategy than wait time. Lots of games have upgrades that take monumental amounts of time.
- I want a game that is easy to start out, has an alliance system, has some form of communication between members, as I hate apps that have clans where you can't even talk to your members.

I just want to know if one exists, as I haven't seen one.

Comment: This question is too broad and too vague, it should not have been migrated here. I'll edit it somewhat (Aha, Unor beat me to it), but it will get closed as 'too broad' or 'unclear what you'are asking' if you cannot be more precise. Asking for *best* should be your number 1 flag that it's not a precise enough question.

Comment: I made the question less vague, that should prevent it from getting closed. As it is I doubt that dozens of solutions exist, so anyone feel free to start giving answers.

Answer (score 1):

**The Battle of Polytopia**

[image: App Store]

- Fast-paced, with little wait time
- Easy to learn
- Has an alliance system and some form of communication
- Well-balanced such that there is no large divide between spenders and free players